# Create file reference to image in Images.xcassets using xcodeproj

Tags: ios, ruby, xcode, xcodeproj

I'm writing a script with [Xcodeproj](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Xcodeproj) and I would like to create references to image files inside `.xcassets.` Finder treats `.xcassets` & `.imageset` as Folders but I don't want to create a group in xcode for each of those folders.

I'm able to create a reference when I know the containing groups in Xcode. i.e. `project.main_group['Src'].new_reference(pathToProject/Src/fileName.m)`

I'd like to iterate through the sub-directories and files of `.xcassets` and create a reference for each image. But I don't want to create a group in Xcode that matches each `imageset` in Finder because Xcode deals with the `.xcassets` folder in its own way.

I would like to be able to do something like this:

`project.main_group['Src']['Images.xcassets']['image_name.imageset']
.new_reference(pathToProject/Src/Images.xcassets/image_name.imageset/image_name.png)`
The above line doesn't work using `Xcodeproj` because it can't find any Groups named `Images.xcassets` or `image_name.imageset.`

Can anyone point me in the right direction or give an example of how I would create a reference to an image file stored inside `Images.xcassets`?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out Xcode handles the image references for you if you add an `.xcassets` file to your project.

Another thing I learned is that the `.xcassets` folder should be added to your target(s) as a resource with `xcodeproj` instead of a file reference. That way it will correctly show up under `Project -> Target -> Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources`.

e.g. `target.add_resources([file_reference_to_xcassets])`
instead of `target.add_file_references([file_reference_to_xcassets])`

Hopefully, this helps someone down the road :)

Comment: Thanks. This helped